# Local Name change for peripheral on Raspberry Pi not reflected on iOS Central app

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluez, bluetooth-peripheral

I have developed BLE Peripheral on my Raspberry pi using Python3, All is working fine but, When i scan this peripheral from my iOS Central app the title always appear to be null.

I have already tried to change the local name with `self.local_name` as follows:

```
self.service_uuids = DBusStringArray([
            SERVICE_UUID])

self.local_name = 'Build by akhzar'
self.include_tx_power = True
```

Comment: yes this is happening because AD Type 0x09 is not added

Please refer 

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AD Type to 0x09 which is used for complete local name but for short local name you can use 0x08.

Check this code may be this helps you

```
    def get_properties(self):
        return {
            'org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1': {
                'Type': 'peripheral',
                'LocalName': 'CC',
                'ServiceUUIDs': DBusStringArray([
                SERVICE_UUID
                ]),
                'IncludeTxPower': True,
            },
        }
```